# Insert character in the middle of numbers for column VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I am trying to enter a "-" after the third digit in the numbers in the picture but don't know the proper VBA code to use to get this to work properly on a column of data.

This is the current code I have:

```
LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("B2:B" & LR).NumberFormat = "###-######"
```

Although this does not add the dash and just changes the formatting. Thus it is not sufficient for when I upload the data to its final spot as it does not recognize the formatting and add the dash.

Is there some type of function I can do to add this "-" after the third character of all these numbers in the column? Thank you

Comment: This is just simple string manipulation.  What have you tried?  And can't you fix this before you bring the data in?

Comment: Are you sure the contents of column B are actually numbers and not text that looks like numbers?

Comment: So you see the `-` in the cells but you want it to persist when exporting to a different format?

Comment: `ws.Range("B2:B" & LR).NumberFormat = "000-######"`
will not change the underlying numbers, but will _display_ a `-` in the 4th position; if you _do_ want to change the numbers to the then-displayed values you will have to loop through the entire range, with a line like this in the loop body: `ws.Cells(i,2).Value = ws.Cells(i,2).Text` where `i` is your iteration variable.

Comment: An alternative to the loop (after changing the display format) is to save your file as a `.csv` (if that's suitable) as that will also preserve the `-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Sub Add_Character()

Dim rng As Range, c As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

LR1 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ws.Range("B2:B" & LR1)
    For Each c In rng
        new_val = WorksheetFunction.Replace(c.Value, 4, 0, "-")
        c.Value = new_val
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code:

```
Sub AddHyphen()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, LR As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Columns("C").Insert
    With ws.Range("B2:B" & LR)
        .Offset(, 1).Formula = "=LEFT(B2,3) & ""-"" & RIGHT(B2,6)"
        .Value = .Offset(, 1).Value
    End With
    ws.Columns("C").Delete
End Sub
```